# Change the title of the mdtheorem box

Tags: theorems

I have the following code for an infobox. I would like to change the title of the infobox, e.g. not have it say `Definition 1.1` but something different, so the title should fit the content.
Unfortunately, I don't quite understand how I can do this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\geometry{paper=a4paper, left=24mm, right=23mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

% Theorem
\mdtheorem[
  linecolor=gray,
  frametitlefont=\sffamily\bfseries\color{Black},
  frametitlebackgroundcolor=gray,
]{Def}{Defintion}[subsection]

%Document 
\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\blindtext
\subsection{Subsection 1.1}
\blindtext

%Infobox
\begin{Def}
\blindtext
\end{Def}

\end{document}
```

My output:

[image]

Comment: do you want to remove the numbers (1.1.1) too? If you just want to change from "definition" to "anotherword" just write {Def}{Anotherword}[subsection]

Comment: yes i want to remove the numbers (subsections) I want to see Defintion: anotherword not Definition: Subsection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you don't actually need to use an `\mdtheorem` for this. Is there any reason you want to?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\geometry{paper=a4paper, left=24mm, right=23mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\mdfdefinestyle{graybox}{
linecolor=gray,
    frametitlefont=\sffamily\bfseries\color{Black},
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=gray,
    frametitle={My Infobox}
    }
    
\begin{document}
    
    \section{Section 1}
    \blindtext
    \subsection{Subsection 1.1}
    \blindtext
    
    \begin{mdframed}[
    style=graybox,
    frametitle={My Infobox}]
    \blindtext
    \end{mdframed}

    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: very helpfull answer! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Replace "Definition" with "anoterword", remove `[subsection]` and use `\begin{Def*} ... \end{Def*}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\geometry{paper=a4paper, left=24mm, right=23mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

% Theorem
\mdtheorem[
linecolor=gray,
frametitlefont=\sffamily\bfseries\color{Black},
frametitlebackgroundcolor=gray,
]{Def}{Anotherword}

%Document 
\begin{document}
    
    \section{Section 1}
    \blindtext
    \subsection{Subsection 1.1}
    \blindtext
    
    %Infobox
    \begin{Def*}
        \blindtext
    \end{Def*}

    \begin{Def*}
    \blindtext
\end{Def*}

    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer however i want to name the boxes different, e.g, the first Box defines ABC and the secound one DEF